# AR friendly where clause with table and field specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How do I convert this to more of more AR  friendly where clause?

```
  relation.where("users.id = (?)", user_id)
end
```

I tried

```
 relation.where(id: ?, user_id)
```

but I need to specify the table since the AR has multiple joins.

As I want to be able to provide just a single user_id or an array of user_ids.

Comment: It seems a little hard to say with so little information. But, have you tried: `relation.where(users: {id: user_id})`? If that works (it might not), then `user_id` can be an integer, an array of ids, an enumerable of users, etc.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, works great, thank you.

Comment: Super. Added as an answer should you with to upvote/accept for future seekers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a little hard to say with so little information. But, have you tried:

```
relation.where(users: {id: user_id})
```

`user_id` can be an integer, an array of ids, an enumerable of users, etc.